# Servlet doPut rejecting my frontend fetch due to CORS

Tags: java, reactjs, servlets, cors, fetch

I'm running a React frontend for my Java WebServlets backend, up until now I've found no trouble with CORS by just using "response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");" to my POST and GET methods. However fetch API PUT requests give me the next error, even with the aforementioned header:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/ControladorPedido' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here's my fetch request:

```
    let handlePago = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();

        let pago = {
            pedido_id : info.id_pedido,
            pedido_pagado : true
        }

        try{
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/ControladorPedido", {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                body: new URLSearchParams(pago)
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
            })
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }

    }
```

Here are my doPut headers:

```
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    pool = conexion.connect();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");

    PrintWriter print = response.getWriter();
}
```

I've tried using "response.setHeader" instead of "response.addHeader" but to no avail.